# AngularJS: How to bind a $scope variable to another $scope.variable

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind a $scope.variable to another $scope.variable like this:

```
$scope.b = '';
$scope.a = $scope.b;
$scope.b = 10;
console.log($scope.a);// It gives blank value
```

In other words, i want to assign $scope.b value to $scope.a whenever $scope.b get a value.

Comment: You could add a watcher to `$scope.b` and update `$scope.a` in the callback.

Comment: Yeah we can add $watch and assign value in the callback but i have around 200 variables which are depending on each other. Do you  have any global  solution for this?

Comment: '..200 variables which are depending on each other..' that just sounds like a minefield. Are you able to give any more context to your set up?

Comment: Suppose i am building a web like excel sheet in which lots of fields are depending on each other values in their calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do a watch:

```
$scope.$watch('b', function (newValue) {
    $scope.a = newValue;
});

$scope.b = 2;
Console.log($scope.a); // Careful! This will still be undefined, explanation below.
```

Angular has a digest loop that it executes to process bindings. If you want you can do a `$scope.$apply()` to instruct angular to run the loop or you can just leave it to do its thing, that's probably what you want in real code.

Comment: Yeah we can add $watch and assign value in the callback but i have around 200 variables which are depending on each other. Do you  have any global  solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us more about your use case? 200 variables depending on each other sounds weird.

Comment: Yeah,  i can understand lots of variable depending on  each other sounds weird, but i have to develop  a realtime web page just like the excel sheet in which lots of columns are depending on each other in their calculations

Comment: Alright, so it's like any variable can have more than one dependent while also depending on other variables?

Comment: Exactly, same like excel  sheet

Comment: You can still use watches, but if too much data exists I believe the best way to go would be registering properties with `Object.defineProperty`. You'd still need to have some kind of process that links all variables together for that to work.

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript you can copy reference to the obj and it will give you what you expect.

You need to do this:

```
$scope.b = {prop: 0};
$scope.a = $scope.b;
$scope.b.prop = 10;
console.log($scope.a.prop);// It gives 10
```

Answer (score 2):

$watch will be called everytime $scope.a changes. If you have multiple data, then you can create a JSON instead of individual variables

```
$scope.tmp = {
  'b' : 22,
  'a' : 33
};
$scope.$watch('tmp', function() {
   $scope.tmp.a = $scope.tmp.b; // Set $scope.a here
}, true);
```

Comment: When watching objects you should pass `true` as the third parameter of `$watch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.defineProperty()` to define one property in terms of another:

```js
function myController($scope) {
  Object.defineProperty($scope, 'b', {
    get: function() {
      return $scope.a;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      $scope.a = value;
    }
  });
  
  $scope.b = 10;
  console.log($scope.a);
  $scope.a = 20;
  console.log($scope.b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Suppose i need to bind 100 of $scope.variables to each other, then? do i need to add this function for each variable or is there any global way?

Comment: i want to develop a realtime web page just like the excel sheet in which lots of columns are depending on each other in their calculations

Comment: This worked well for my case. I had a string like "Hello, [name1] & [name2]" and the name variables would change with a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can copy objects references, As what you are doing is copying the value of `b` to `a` even if you want to copy the reference. Because `$scope.b` is primitive type data. If you want to copy its reference it should be of non-primitive type.
as,

```
$scope.b = {c:''};
$scope.a = $scope.b;
$scope.a.c = 10;
console.log($scope.b.c); //output 10
```